# ¿Cómo puedo incluir un identificador de mi venta para impactar en mi sistema cobrando a través de Mercado Pago?

Tags: mercadopago

Necesito poder hacer una búsqueda al final del día de todas las ventas finalizadas para crear la ruta de distribución óptima al día siguiente. Para esto necesito recibir información adicional sobre la venta para poder identificarla en mi sistema.

¿Cómo puedo enviar información adicional en los datos de creación de una preferencia?

Mi código es :

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => $sale_items
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

Y para buscar las ventas uso el endpoint

`api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/searchcollector.id=me&date_approved=fecha_hoy`

Answer (score 2):

Enviá el atributo **external_reference** en la preferencia de pago (si usas **checkout** básico) o directamente en el pago (si usas el **checkout** personalizado) con el *id* en tu sistema.

Cuando recibas una notificación y hagas el *GET* para obtener la información del pago, recibirás el **external_reference** para asociar el pago recibido a través de *Mercado Pago* con la venta en tu sitio.
Podés hacer un *search* a la *API* de **Payments** buscando el pago asociado a una **external_reference**:

https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/search?external_reference=EXTERNAL_REFERENCE&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN